Why does io_uring read a file so slowly in polling mode?
Problem Summary
I am working on a project that requires using io_uring with polling mode, but now I have encountered two problems:

I need to run it several times before I can output the content; otherwise, it will be stuck in a long wait.

Reading a file is really slow. For example:



Hello world!


This is reading a file content. It is a really small file, but it still needs more than 10 seconds.
Additional Information

My Linux system kernel version is 6.9.5-1-default.
I must use the IORING_SETUP_SQPOLL flag because I don't want to use the io_uring_enter system call, and must utilize the submission queue polling feature.
I don't want to use any liburing API.
Even after I remove sleep(10), it is still as slow as before and does not produce any results.

Questions

Could you please tell me why I need to run it several times for the file content to be output?

Could you please tell me why io_uring reads a file so slowly in polling mode?


Code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>  // For PRIdMAX
#include <sys/types.h> // For off_t

/* If your compilation fails because the header file below is missing,
 * your kernel is probably too old to support io_uring.
 * */
#include <linux/io_uring.h>

#define QUEUE_DEPTH 128
#define BLOCK_SZ    4096
int first;
/* This is x86 specific */
#define read_barrier()  __asm__ __volatile__("":::"memory")
#define write_barrier() __asm__ __volatile__("":::"memory")

/* Macros for barriers needed by io_uring */
#define io_uring_smp_store_release(p, v)            \
    atomic_store_explicit((_Atomic typeof(*(p)) *)(p), (v), \
                  memory_order_release)
#define io_uring_smp_load_acquire(p)                \
    atomic_load_explicit((_Atomic typeof(*(p)) *)(p),   \
                 memory_order_acquire)
struct app_io_sq_ring {
    unsigned *head;
    unsigned *tail;
    unsigned *ring_mask;
    unsigned *ring_entries;
    unsigned *flags;
    unsigned *array;
};

struct app_io_cq_ring {
    unsigned *head;
    unsigned *tail;
    unsigned *ring_mask;
    unsigned *ring_entries;
    struct io_uring_cqe *cqes;
};

struct submitter {
    int ring_fd;
    struct app_io_sq_ring sq_ring;
    struct io_uring_sqe *sqes;
    struct app_io_cq_ring cq_ring;
};

struct file_info {
    off_t file_sz;
    struct iovec iovecs[];      /* Referred by readv/writev */
};

typedef struct {
  FILE *fp;
  struct submitter *s;
  struct file_info *fi;
} my_file;


/*
 * This code is written in the days when io_uring-related system calls are not
 * part of standard C libraries. So, we roll our own system call wrapper
 * functions.
 * */

int io_uring_setup(unsigned entries, struct io_uring_params *p)
{
    return (int) syscall(__NR_io_uring_setup, entries, p);
}

int io_uring_enter(int ring_fd, unsigned int to_submit,
                          unsigned int min_complete, unsigned int flags)
{
    return (int) syscall(__NR_io_uring_enter, ring_fd, to_submit, min_complete,
                   flags, NULL, 0);
}

int io_uring_register(unsigned int fd, unsigned int opcode,
                      const void *arg, unsigned int nr_args)
{
    return (int) syscall(__NR_io_uring_register, fd, opcode, arg, nr_args);
}


off_t get_file_size(int fd) {
    struct stat st;

    if(fstat(fd, &st) < 0) {
        perror("fstat");
        return -1;
    }
    if (S_ISBLK(st.st_mode)) {
        unsigned long long bytes;
        if (ioctl(fd, BLKGETSIZE64, &bytes) != 0) {
            perror("ioctl");
            return -1;
        }
        return bytes;
    } else if (S_ISREG(st.st_mode))
        return st.st_size;

    return -1;
}

off_t get_file_size2(FILE *file) {
    struct stat st;
    int fd = fileno(file);  // 获取与 FILE* 关联的文件描述符

    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("fileno");
        return -1;
    }

    if (fstat(fd, &st) < 0) {
        perror("fstat");
        return -1;
    }

    if (S_ISBLK(st.st_mode)) {
        unsigned long long bytes;
        if (ioctl(fd, BLKGETSIZE64, &bytes) != 0) {
            perror("ioctl");
            return -1;
        }
        return bytes;
    } else if (S_ISREG(st.st_mode)) {
        return st.st_size;
    }

    return -1;
}


int app_setup_uring(struct submitter *s) {
    memset(s, 0, sizeof(*s));
    struct app_io_sq_ring *sring = &s->sq_ring;
    struct app_io_cq_ring *cring = &s->cq_ring;
    struct io_uring_params p;
    void *sq_ptr, *cq_ptr;

    memset(&p, 0, sizeof(p));
    p.flags |= IORING_SETUP_SQPOLL;
    p.flags |= IORING_SETUP_SQ_AFF;
    p.sq_thread_idle = 20000;
    p.sq_thread_cpu = 4;
    s->ring_fd = io_uring_setup(QUEUE_DEPTH, &p);
    if (s->ring_fd < 0) {
      perror("io_uring_setup");
      return 1;
    }

    int sring_sz = p.sq_off.array + p.sq_entries * sizeof(unsigned);
    int cring_sz = p.cq_off.cqes + p.cq_entries * sizeof(struct io_uring_cqe);

    if (p.features & IORING_FEAT_SINGLE_MMAP) {
        if (cring_sz > sring_sz) {
            sring_sz = cring_sz;
        }
        cring_sz = sring_sz;
    }

    sq_ptr = mmap(0, sring_sz, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
            MAP_SHARED | MAP_POPULATE,
            s->ring_fd, IORING_OFF_SQ_RING);
    if (sq_ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        return 1;
    }

    if (p.features & IORING_FEAT_SINGLE_MMAP) {
        cq_ptr = sq_ptr;
    } else {
        /* Map in the completion queue ring buffer in older kernels separately */
        cq_ptr = mmap(0, cring_sz, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
                MAP_SHARED | MAP_POPULATE,
                s->ring_fd, IORING_OFF_CQ_RING);
        if (cq_ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
            perror("mmap");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    sring->head = sq_ptr + p.sq_off.head;
    sring->tail = sq_ptr + p.sq_off.tail;
    sring->ring_mask = sq_ptr + p.sq_off.ring_mask;
    sring->ring_entries = sq_ptr + p.sq_off.ring_entries;
    sring->flags = sq_ptr + p.sq_off.flags;
    sring->array = sq_ptr + p.sq_off.array;

    s->sqes = mmap(0, p.sq_entries * sizeof(struct io_uring_sqe),
            PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_POPULATE,
            s->ring_fd, IORING_OFF_SQES);
    if (s->sqes == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        return 1;
    }

    cring->head = cq_ptr + p.cq_off.head;
    cring->tail = cq_ptr + p.cq_off.tail;
    cring->ring_mask = cq_ptr + p.cq_off.ring_mask;
    cring->ring_entries = cq_ptr + p.cq_off.ring_entries;
    cring->cqes = cq_ptr + p.cq_off.cqes;

    return 0;
}

void output_to_console(char *buf, int len) {
    while (len--) {
        fputc(*buf++, stdout);
    }
}


void my_fread(size_t size, size_t count, my_file *restrict mf) {
    struct submitter*s = mf->s;
    struct file_info *fi;
    struct app_io_cq_ring *cring = &s->cq_ring;
    struct io_uring_cqe *cqe;
    size_t total_bytes = size * count;
    unsigned head, reaped = 0;

    head = *cring->head;

    do {
        read_barrier();

        if (head == *cring->tail)
            break;

        /* Get the entry */
        cqe = &cring->cqes[head & *s->cq_ring.ring_mask];
        fi = (struct file_info*) cqe->user_data;
        if (cqe->res < 0)
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", strerror(abs(cqe->res)));

        int blocks = (int) total_bytes / BLOCK_SZ;
        if (total_bytes % BLOCK_SZ) blocks++;

        for (int i = 0; i < blocks; i++)
            output_to_console(fi->iovecs[i].iov_base, fi->iovecs[i].iov_len);

        head++;
    } while (1);

    *cring->head = head;
    write_barrier();
}

my_file *my_fopen(const char *filename, const char *mode) {
    struct submitter *s = malloc(sizeof(struct submitter));
    struct file_info *fi;
    if(app_setup_uring(s)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to setup uring!\n");
        free(s);
        return NULL;
    }

    // TODO: Write file
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, mode);
    if (!fp) {
        printf("Fopen Failed!");
        return NULL;
    }
    int fd = fileno(fp);

    if (fd < 0) {
       printf("Fopen fileno");
        return NULL;
    }

    //printf("fd is %d, fd1 is %d\n", fd, fd1);
    struct app_io_sq_ring *sring = &s->sq_ring;
    unsigned index = 0, current_block = 0, tail = 0, next_tail = 0;

    off_t file_sz = get_file_size2(fp);
    printf("The size of the file is: %" PRIdMAX " bytes\n", (intmax_t)file_sz);
    if (file_sz < 0)
      return NULL;
    off_t bytes_remaining = file_sz;
    int blocks = (int)file_sz / BLOCK_SZ;
    if (file_sz % BLOCK_SZ)
      blocks++;
    
    fi = malloc(sizeof(*fi) + sizeof(struct iovec) * blocks);
    if (!fi) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory\n");
         return NULL;
    }
    fi->file_sz = file_sz;
    my_file *mf = malloc(sizeof(my_file));;
    mf->s = s;
    mf->fi = fi;
    mf->fp = fp;

    while (bytes_remaining) {
      off_t bytes_to_read = bytes_remaining;
      if (bytes_to_read > BLOCK_SZ)
        bytes_to_read = BLOCK_SZ;

      fi->iovecs[current_block].iov_len = bytes_to_read;

      void *buf;
      if (posix_memalign(&buf, BLOCK_SZ, BLOCK_SZ)) {
        perror("posix_memalign");
        return NULL;
      }
      fi->iovecs[current_block].iov_base = buf;

      current_block++;
      bytes_remaining -= bytes_to_read;
    }

    /* Add our submission queue entry to the tail of the SQE ring buffer */
    next_tail = tail = *sring->tail;
    next_tail++;
    read_barrier();
    index = tail & *s->sq_ring.ring_mask;
    struct io_uring_sqe *sqe = &s->sqes[index];
    sqe->fd = fd;
    sqe->flags = 0;
    sqe->opcode = IORING_OP_READV;
    sqe->addr = (unsigned long)fi->iovecs;
    sqe->len = blocks;
    sqe->off = 0;
    sqe->user_data = (unsigned long long)fi;
    sring->array[index] = index;
    tail = next_tail;

    if (*sring->tail != tail) {
      *sring->tail = tail;
      write_barrier();
    }

    if ((*sring->flags) & IORING_SQ_NEED_WAKEUP) {
      first++;
      int ret = io_uring_enter(s->ring_fd, 1, 1, IORING_ENTER_GETEVENTS);
      if (ret < 0) {
        perror("io_uring_enter");
        return NULL;
      }
    }
    return mf;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    first = 0;
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        my_file *mf = my_fopen(argv[i], "r");
        if (mf != NULL) {
            sleep(10);
            my_fread(mf->fi->file_sz, 1,mf);
        }
        else {
            printf("Fopen Fail!");
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("io_uring_enter times = %d\n", first);
    return 0;
}


Commands
$ gcc test.c -o example
$ ./example file_path1 file_path2

I hope this example reads files quickly in polling mode.

sleep(10); in main's loop seems like the obvious culprit.  Your program always sleeps for 10 seconds before doing any more I/O with the my_fopen result.  It sleeps 10 seconds for each arg separately, not queuing up parallel opens and reads on argv[i], so the best-case speed is 10 seconds per file because that's how your main works.

I am really happy to receive your comment. However, even after removing the sleep(10), it is still very slow and there is no output!

Indeed, strace ./a.out  myfile shows it not even reaching the sleep, so apparently something is timing-sensitive. (Blocked on io_uring_enter(3, 1, 1, IORING_ENTER_GETEVENTS, NULL, 0 ).  I don't know enough about io_uring, but maybe there's some kind of race condition in the way you're using it and it can get stuck?  The same binary works (slowly) if run not under strace, compiled with gcc or gcc -Og on my x86-64 Arch GNU/Linux system, but also gets stuck when single-stepping in GDB.

Yes, I encountered the same problem. This is the issue I want to resolve. I also debugged this example with GDB, but I still don't understand. I really need io_uring with polling mode to read a file.
